# Splitting a String in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that is a length of 2. I was wondering if it was possible to split a string and retrieve the numeric portion of that string.

For example my string is R2, and I want the "2" how would I be able to get the numeric part? 
All the times the letters goes before the number, so F7 or P4 would also qualify in this case.

Comment: var resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value; use this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the string is of length 2 and the character you want is the second one (index = 1). You can just use `YouString(1)` to get that character.

```vb
Dim x As String = "F2"
Dim c As Char = x(1)
Console.WriteLine("The numberic char is: " + c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, is the first letter ALWAYS ONLY 1 letter?

Then

```
K1
K1234
```

Use this to return a double:

```
Val(Mid(str, 2))
```

So the above starts at 2 and returns as many chars as the string is long.
Val converts the result into a double value.

You might want a integer, so this also would work fine:

```
cint(mid(str,2))
```

Comment: Val? Mid? Even I haven't used these for years. :~)

Comment: How true! But hey, those first experiences on an Apple II or old computers STILL comes in handy when using vb.net. Kind of why I use vb.net as opposed to c# when I can! Ah, the good old days! Now just where is that Oregon Trail disk for my Apple II?

Answer (score 0):

If you're always checking the last character, you can use 
    `Dim isANumber As Boolean = IsNumeric(Right(testString, 1))` 
Alternatively, you can loop through the string and use the IsNumeric() function on each character.